# displaying on console

Tags: c

```
printf(" Src Address\n");
for(i = 0;i < 4;i++)
    printf(" %d ",((ip->ip_src.s_addr)&(0x0FF<<(i*8)))>>(i*8));
```

this displays o/p as 127.0.0.0 as i am using loopback but when i do the same 2 display  ethernet address using the same

```
for(i = 0;i <6; i++)
    printf("dest ether:%c",((ethernet->ether_dhost)&(0x0FF<<(i*8)))>>(i*8));
```

the error i get is error: invalid operands to binary &

here u_char ether_dhost[6]; and the variable that store ip address is of type unsigned long int...how to display ethernet address..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `s_addr` field is a 32-bit integer that stores an IPv4 address. Using the binary `&` operator on this works fine. The `ether_dhost` field, OTOH, is a 6-byte array, and you can't manipulate it like you do `s_addr`. But then again, you don't have to:

```
for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    printf(":%c"+!i, ethernet->ether_dhost[i]);
```

Incidentally, your IP address code is much more complicated than it needs to be:

```
for(i = 0; i < 32; i += 8)
    printf(".%d"+!i, (ip->ip_src.s_addr>>i)&0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the standard `struct inet_addr` and `struct ether_addr`, there's standard functions for that.

```
printf("inet address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(…));
printf("ether address: %s\n", ether_ntoa(…));
```